# Condicionales en la creacion de carpetas y el modulo os

Tags: python, while

Cabe aclarar que soy bastante nuevo tanto en python como en programación.

Alguien podría explicarme como hacer que, en vez de que el modulo os me marque el error de que la carpeta ya existe, me lance la indicación de que ya existe y a su vez me permita ingresar un nuevo nombre creando una nueva carpeta, todo esto dentro de un while ya que ando haciendo un bucle.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: La forma normal de atrapar condiciones excepcionales es con `try-except`